# Sort View based upon a specific order of a lookup column

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, sorting, grouping, codeplex

Our standard setup when a department requires a document library with document types is to create a separate Custom List for the Document Types so a power user within that department can add new document types when they need them (over using the choice column). This works pretty well, but we have one department that is trying to recreate the order of their handbook in their document types.
While I can add in a sort order value into the Document Types list, I can't get that to be the order that is used when I group and sort the Document Library. I did find the codeplex for the custom filter lookup column, that only seems to work in the drop down when setting the properties for the document
I thought about using a workflow to then copy over the value to equal another sort order, but they can end up easily changing the sort order at any given time in the future.
How can I get the order that is available in the drop down menu to be the order the documents are grouped and sorted by within a view of the Document Library?